# SP return null as ZERO?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Using a stored procedure i have a fairly complex SQL statement which returns a COUNT value as a pseudo column. In many cases the result will be 'null'. This causes problems in my application, so i am wondering if it is possible to return a 'null' as '0' by default from the stored procedure?

Thanks.

UPDATE

I need to apply the ISNULL to the following statement;

```
    select recip_Chosen, recip_CampaignId) AS ChosenCount
    from TBL_CAMPAIGNRECIPIENTS
    WHERE recip_CampaignId =  @campaign
    group by recip_Chosen
```

Which should be something like;

```
    select recip_Chosen, ISNULL(count(recip_CampaignId),0) AS ChosenCount
    from TBL_CAMPAIGNRECIPIENTS
    WHERE recip_CampaignId =  @campaign
    group by recip_Chosen
```

However, this still returns null(s) in the ChosenCount column. Any ideas?

UPDATE

Ok so the above statement is part of a much larger one as shown below. Here is the full Stored Procedure, but not the table structure since it involves several tables. I only need 'ChosenCount' to return '0' instead of Null. The SP does return 1 row for each record in TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES where it corresponds to TBL_CAMPAIGNS.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE web.getPublicCampaignData
   (
   @campaign BIGINT
   )
AS
BEGIN

SELECT * 
FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
INNER JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M
    ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
INNER JOIN TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES CC
    ON C.campaign_Key = CC.camchar_CampaignID
INNER JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH
    ON CC.camchar_CharityID = CH.cha_Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select recip_Chosen, count(recip_CampaignId) as ChosenCount
    from TBL_CAMPAIGNRECIPIENTS
    WHERE recip_CampaignId =  @campaign
    group by recip_Chosen
) CRC
on CH.cha_Key = CRC.recip_Chosen
WHERE C.campaign_Key = @campaign;

END
```

Comment: How is this COUNT column implemented to "count" NULL instead of 0?

Comment: Updated question with full statement.

Comment: Well, the trouble is: you're doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN here, so if there's no data to be displayed based on the `on CH.cha_Key = CRC.recip_Chosen` condition, then there's nothing at all present there. The SELECT inside the LEFT OUTER JOIN will not be executed at all, so that's why the ISNULL never gets a chance to do its work

Comment: See my updated post - I tried to show how to re-order your SProc in order to make ISNULL work for you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:

```
RETURN ISNULL(yourvalue, 0)
```

What this basically means:

- if "yourvalue" (either a computed value, or the value of a @variable) is NOT NULL, then return that value
- if "yourvalue" IS NULL, then return the second parameter (here "0") instead

I don't know exactly how you compute your count - I assume you're assigning it to some local variable in your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoMyCount()
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @MyCountVariable INT

   SET @MyCountVariable = SELECT COUNT(*)......... -- whatever you do here

   RETURN ISNULL(@MyCountVariable, 0)
END
```

In this case, your stored procedure `dbo.DoMyCount` will return a count (however you computed that), or "0" (zero) is that count comes out to NULL.

That way, you can be sure to always get back a valid NON-NULL INT value from the stored procedure.

Marc

**UPDATE:**

The stored proc makes it clear why the ISNULL doesn't work - it's being used inside a LEFT OUTER JOIN. If no data matches, then the whole select inside the LEFT OUTER JOIN will never be called --> the ISNULL never gets a chance to do its work.

You need to restructure your stored proc a bit:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE web.getPublicCampaignData(@campaign BIGINT)
AS BEGIN
  SELECT
     (list of fields), ISNULL(CRC.ChosenCount, 0), .....
  FROM TBL_CAMPAIGNS C
  INNER JOIN TBL_MEMBERS M 
     ON C.campaign_MemberId = M.members_Id
  INNER JOIN TBL_CAMPAIGNS_CHARITIES CC 
     ON C.campaign_Key = CC.camchar_CampaignID
  INNER JOIN TBL_CHARITIES CH 
    ON CC.camchar_CharityID = CH.cha_Key
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select recip_Chosen, count(recip_CampaignId) as ChosenCount
    from TBL_CAMPAIGNRECIPIENTS
    WHERE recip_CampaignId =  @campaign
    group by recip_Chosen
  ) CRC on CH.cha_Key = CRC.recip_Chosen
  WHERE 
     C.campaign_Key = @campaign;
END
```

That way, if the `CH.cha_Key = CRC.recip_Chosen` doesn't match and the LEFT OUTER JOIN returns NULLs, it will be caught and the ChosenCount = NULL will be turned into a "0".

Comment: best choice, ISNULL is faster than COALESCE(which is CASE WHEN THEN END, most people don't know that)

Comment: Svetlozar's right, and this should be accepted answer. Mine is a more-you-know type of answer. Marc had already won my +1.

Comment: Marc, thanks for the answer. Could you please break down what is happening here so i can fully understand it, and thus learn from it.

Thanks.

Comment: Updated my question with details of the statement. Please take a look.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from [`isnull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) on SQL Server, I'm a big fan of [`coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), since that takes any number of arguments. For two arguments, it's functionally equivalent to `isnull`:

```
return coalesce(yourvalue, 0)
```

Is the same as:

```
return isnull(yourvalue, 0)
```

However,

`coalesce(yourvalue, backupval, 0)`

is equivalent to

`isnull(isnull(yourvalue, backupval), 0)`

Obviously, `coalesce` is much more readable in this case, so that's why I'm a fan.

Apologies for a long-winded answer on a very simple question, but hey, why not learn something else, eh?

Comment: COALESCE isn't quite equivalent to ISNULL, as COALESCE handles having multiple data types as the objects, where ISNULL requires that the data types be the same.  ISNULL('test', 0) will fail, where COALESCE('test', 0) will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
select isnull(sum(size),0) as total_size from my_table where is_valid = 1
```

Comment: Updated my question with details of the statement. Please take a look, since i tried this approach but without success. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ISNULL is maybe faster bur it's specific to SQLServer.

COALESCE is ANSI standard

[Here's some differences and other explanations about ISNULL and COALESCE](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html)

Comment: faster is always better, if in the rare event you ever port code there will be a million other more difficult problems, but a search and replace from _ISNULL_ to _COALESCE_ is very easy...